# Can I get a list of all the modules that are currently loaded?

Tags: module, erlang

module_info will tell me quite a bit of what I need to know about a module - provided that I know its name.  I have a need to find all modules whose names meet specific criteria (like companyname_creator_serialnumber.)  I remember reading somewhere that erlang stores this information, but I am looking for a way to retrieve it.

EDIT:

all_loaded() returns all the modules that have been loaded, but if the module I'm looking for hasn't been referenced yet, it isn't in the all_loaded list.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
code:all_loaded().
```

Comment: all_loaded() returns all the modules that have been loaded, but if the module I'm looking for hasn't been referenced yet, it isn't in the all_loaded list.

Comment: Ah, then you would have to do filelib:wildcard on all paths in code:get_path() and look for the beam file

Comment: @Lukas is right. Its better to use `code:get_path()` and then search for your own. A module may not yet be loaded but its in the path. It will be loaded as soon as a call is made to a function in that module

Comment: Yes, the system can't give you any information about a module before it has been loaded. There is also a BIF `erlang:loaded/0` which returns a list of all the modules in the system.